# Adding Controls dynamically. Asp.Net and VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to add a "panel" with controls dynamicaly. Something like the code below, Clicking "Add" button, displays a "Panel" with the controls(which are within a table), the number of "Education" someone can enter is unlimited. I know how to capture the data, but i can't figure out how to implement/code this,Can anyone please give me some pointers for the same?
      Should i be reading about AJAX? I don't know anything about AJAX..

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="CollUniv_Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="CollUniv_Location" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="StartDateText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="EndDateText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you seen this post: [Copy/Clone Control](http://forums.asp.net/t/617980.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would more naturally handled by a repeating control.  Something along the lines of a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) control.

There's a fairly full example in the MSDN page I linked to so I won't repeat it here.  The two parts you'll want to take a look at a bit more closely are the `ItemTemplate` which lets you define what normal items look like and the `InsertItemTemplate` which lets you specify what your insert row will look like.  You can also specify if the InsertTemplate appears at the top or bottom.  In the code-behind you'll subscribe to the [ItemInserting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.iteminserting.aspx) even and handle user input from there.